# "ReferenceError: Plugin is not defined" when launching Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, plugins, package, referenceerror

So basically I had a little issue where I accidentally deleted like 90% of the project folder's files (including the .meteor folder), and after recovering them, I can't seem to load/launch Meteor. I'm getting this error:

```
/home/edin/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.9.ltydx3++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
                    throw(ex);
                          ^
ReferenceError: Plugin is not defined
at path (caching-compiler.js:1:12)
at /home/edin/Apps/blog/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/caching-compiler.js:482:4
at multi-file-caching-compiler.js:216:2
at /home/edin/Apps/blog/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:242:10
at Array.forEach (native)
at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/edin/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.9.ltydx3++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
at /home/edin/Apps/blog/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:137:5
Exited with code: 8
Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

I thought it might have been a package problem, so I tried reinstalling/updating them. Nothing. Then I tried creating a new project, installing the packages on there fresh and pasting all of my work files there. Nothing again. I can't seem to wrap my head around this error. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score -1):

Create a new clean Meteor project. Copy your own files into that project as well as the `packages.json` which exists in the `.meteor` folder.

Running `meteor reset` or `meteor update` on the command line is another avenue you could try, but I'm not sure those will help. I'd just start again if I was you.

Comment: Exactly what @Kyll said. `meteor reset` and `meteor update` didn't help either. Any other ideas? I guess I could try rebuilding the project step by step and looking at what the problem is... I was hoping I'd be able to find a quicker solution.